# SQL Server Azure VM with 512e SSD Storage - Error 9012

Tags: sql-server, azure-vm, ssd

I have been given a SQL Server Azure VM that has 512e storage attached for data and log files, according to `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo [drive letter]:\`.

It is a DR replication node from an on-premises server with 512 storage drives.

The VM is reporting 9012 error, which could be due to the storage or due to the difference between the replication server and the primary server.

I am trying to assess if this is a cause for concern for both Availability Groups delay and for optimal SQL Server setup, if I were to turn it into a primary.

Everything I am reading seems to say that [512e and SQL Server is not recommended.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-server-new-drives-use-4k-sector-size) But the articles are from 2011 - hasn't anything changed in 11 years? Or is 512e still not the way to go.

Azure documentation does not mention any of this and I can only gather that 512e may be optional for the new SSD disks.

Note: Enabling trace flag 1800 did not resolve the error.

Microsoft don't even recommend HDD, listing them as recommended for Dev only now.  I am waiting to see if I have ability to open a support ticket, but wanted to know people's experience here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

512e is supported for below OS/SQL Server versions.

Errors for misaligned logs come up when using mirroring or log shipping for servers on different drive sectors.

> SQL Server 2008 R2 PCU 1 with the associated Windows QFEs support activity against 512e drives because the QFEs allow SQL Server to determine the proper physical sector size and align on the physical size properly.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/sql-server-new-drives-use-4k-sector-size/ba-p/316277

Comment: The article you quote says, "First published on MSDN on Jan 13, 2011". It is the same article linked to in the question, just hosted in a different place.

Comment: Admittedly yes, it took a while to see the fine print at the bottom, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing has changed in the last 11 years and 512e is still not the way to go. However is horrifying that Microsoft is proposing such HD on SQL Server Azure VM.

On [this forum](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/512e-advanced-format-drives) I found a person that was experiencing the same around 2015. There is apparently an Hot Fix that was released by Microsoft [KB3009974](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3009974-fix-slow-synchronization-when-disks-have-different-sector-sizes-for-primary-and-secondary-replica-log-files-in-sql-server-ag-and-logshipping-environments-ed181bf3-ce80-b6d0-f268-34135711043c).

This makes me think that you are probably on SQL Server 2012-2014 and you might have done Lift & Shift to Azure VM. Maybe that's why Azure is providing you the 512e SSD storage. (Old OS might need the same old compatible hardware? Cannot tell...)

Run these commands to check if the Hot Fix has been applied to your computer:

```
dism /online /get-packages | findstr KB3009974
```

or

```
SYSTEMINFO.exe | findstr KB3009974
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you. No actually I am on SQL 2016 / Windows 2016 Datacenter - I read that forum 3x times now and the last comment (where the OP cannot remember how he resolved the issue) is unfortunate. Yes MS is pushing new SSD drives

Comment: Still no luck and getting the run around from Microsoft support. I am basically told this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/advanced-format-disk-compatibility-update even though it is not a reslution.